# how to transfer data from an activty to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am beginner in android. I am trying to find a way to transfer the text from the editText of an an activity to the fragment so that the result is displayed in the textview of the fragment.

Comment: You should really use the Fragment as the entire UI with the EditText itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can use bundle to transfer data from activity to fragment

I suppose data will be sent on button click.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("from_activity", edittext.getText().toString());
Fragmentclass fragment= new Fragmentclass();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

In fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    String text= getArguments().getString("from_activity"); 
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
   tv.setText(text);   
    return view;
}
```

Comment: This uses a hard-coded string, not a value from an EditText like the question asked

Comment: Corrected as per need :)

Comment: Well, except `edittext.getText().toString()` would be empty while the view is loaded

Comment: @cricket_007 edittext.getText().toString() will be taken on button click. It will not be null.

Comment: It won't  be empty if it is taken on button click action correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That is correct, but it is worth mentioning in case your code was to be copied into onCreate directly

Comment: I have added comments above now looks fine :)